# Using the presence/absence of errors as conditionals with if/elsif/else in Ruby

Tags: ruby

What's Ruby for the following?

```
if executing the next line wouldn't cause any kind of error then
  execute this line
elsif executing the next line wouldn't cause any kind of error then
  execute this line
else
```

I've been reading the API pages for rescue and exceptions and eval but so far have failed in my quest.

Many thanks,

Steven.

---

Following on from a [comment](http://twitter.com/assaf/statuses/3930094823) from Assaf Arkin, I'm going to suggest the following syntax:

```
if first_condition
 execute_this_line rescue nil
elsif second_condition
 execute_that_line rescue nil
end
```

Will the result be as follows?

> If first_condition is true and it's
>   possible to execute_this_line without
>   error, then it will execute_this_line.
>
> If first_condition is true and
>   execute_this_line normally generates
>   an error, it will jump to end.
>
> If first-condition is false, it will
>   test second_condition.
>
> If second_condition is true and it's
>   possible to execute_that_line without
>   error, then it will execute_that_line.
>
> Otherwise it will jump to end.

Comment: Are you actually asking how to make Ruby predict the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I think I need:

```
if first_condition rescue nil
 execute_this_line
elsif second_condition rescue nil
 execute_that_line
end
```

Will the result be as follows?

> If first_condition is true, then it will execute_this_line.
>
> If first_condition is false or generates an error, it will jump to second_condition without action throwing an error.
>
> etc...

Answer (score 1):

I'll rename your pseudocode to clarify:

```
if lineA doesn't cause an error
  execute lineA
elsif lineB doesn't cause an error
  execute lineB
end
```

Is this right in the way you wanted it? Then why not use

```
begin
  lineA
rescue
  error_handling
ensure
  lineB
end
```

If you want to do more of this you can nest it and for sure it's a good idea to refactor some new methods out of it.

Alternativly the shorthand:

```
valA = lineA rescue StandardError
lineB if valA.is_a?(Exception)
```

And of course you can repeat this as many times as you'd like to! ;)

Comment: Thanks Xijo. Yes, your rewritten pseudocode capture my intention, so I'll have a crack at working your Ruby code into mine. Thanks again.

Comment: the begin...ensure does lineA and lineB, but the shorthand fixes that.